# How do I change the hotkey for multiple selection in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to change the hotkey in Android Studio for what is called "multiple selection" in Sublime Text. The default hotkey on mac is alt+shift+click.  What is this called by Android Studio, so I can change it to be the same as Sublime text?

Thanks!

P.S.  I am unable to find this hotkey from preferences->keymap, the search by hotkey pattern seems to not work with alt or shift, and google is being very unhelpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android studio it is called "Add or Remove Caret". It is under Editor Actions.